# Spring Boot and ebextensions

Tags: maven, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-elb, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to add an .ebextensions folder to the root level of my jar to be deployed to AWS elastic beanstalk.

My folder structure is:

```
main:
--src
--resources
  --.ebextensions
```

When I build the jar my `.ebextensions` gets placed on the classpath of my target and therefore is not picked up by Elastic Beanstalk on deploy.

Pom.xml

```
<plugin>
     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
     <configuration>
           <fork>true</fork>
           <addResources>false</addResources>
     </configuration>
</plugin>
```

How can I build so that ebextensions is picked up by ELB?

Comment: You'll probably be interested in [this Spring Boot issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/6626).

Comment: Actually, are you sure you want the file in the root of the jar? [The documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/java-se-platform.html) suggests that `.ebextensions` should sit next to your jar file in your application source bundle.

Comment: Create a source bundle: https://medium.com/@autumn.bom/deploying-spring-boot-jar-application-on-beanstalk-java-se-platform-45d8d04608ae

Comment: From the document referenced above: "Location – Place all of your configuration files in a single folder, named .ebextensions, in the root of your source bundle. Folders starting with a dot can be hidden by file browsers, so make sure that the folder is added when you create your source bundle."

Comment: I can confirm that it needs to be in the root of the jar. I state this after days of working with AWS support. But I will state that this is for Java8 and Tomcat running on Amazon Linux 1. Linux 2 is different.

Answer (score 26):

This works for me, is the cleanest way (in maven) I found to solve this:

Add .ebextensions in the root of your project and add this snippet at the end in the plugins section:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>prepare</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <tasks>
                            <unzip src="${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.jar" dest="${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}" />
                            <copy todir="${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/" overwrite="false">
                                <fileset dir="./" includes=".ebextensions/**"/>
                            </copy>
                            <zip compress="false" destfile="${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.jar" basedir="${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}"/>
                        </tasks>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

This plugin use ant to unzip the final jar generated by spring boot, copy the .ebextensions in the root and zip (jar) again with the same name. Tested and working in production :)

Works with Spring 1.5.3.RELEASE

Comment: Very useful +1. By chance do you know an updated plugin that does the same? Last code from `maven-antrun-plugin` is from 2014.

Comment: Very handy! I prefer to name the source folder without a leading period, so that my OS doesn't hide it, and to include AWS in the path. Somewthing like: `src/main/aws/ebextensions`. It gets renamed to `.ebextensions` when I copy it into the zip.

Comment: Some might find this a better alternative: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64911750/3112373

Comment: This sets the folder name as "ebextensions", not ".ebextensions"

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problems, moving `.ebextensions` next to the jar as Andy suggested worked for me when I combined it with directly adding a `.conf` file to the desired directory as suggested here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/41011160/7686379

Answer (score 1):

For those of you using Gradle, here is what needs to be added to your build.gradle in order to add the .ebextensions stuff to the root of the jar.

It assumes that the .ebextensions directory and contents are in the root of your project.

Normal Java app:

```
jar {
    from(".") {
        include ".ebextensions/**"
    }
}
```

Spring Boot app:

```
bootJar {
    from(".") {
        include ".ebextensions/**"
    }
}
```

The Spring Boot case is slightly different to the normal Java case because with Spring Boot it is the Spring Boot Gradle plugin that actually constructs the jar - and it uses a special "bootJar" task in place of the standard Java plugin "jar" task.

I think that for Maven builds, Javier's answer is the cleanest way to go. For me, this illustrates the flexibility of Gradle over Maven when modifying "standard" builds.

Answer (score 0):

For all of you who might struggle with this. Have a directory in the root of your project that looks like this: .ebextentions/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf In the proxy.conf file you place this client_max_body_size 50M; which does exactly that. Now when you upload your project to elastic beanstalk, what you do is you make a zipped folder, and then you copy your target folder and the .ebextensions directory into it this is called a source bundle. Now you can upload the zipped folder(bundle) to elastic beanstalk.

Comment: This does work but is manually in nature. Can be automated with maven-ant-plugin

Answer (score 0):

Here is how i did it:
Ran `mvn install` which generated `app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`
After that i have created `.ebextensions/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf` on root project path which has `client_max_body_size 25M;` - in my case was to increase maximum upload size.
Using Github Actions and ubuntu-latest for the runner - the zip command is supported out of the box and i did it with this command

```
cp target/app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar . && zip -r app-new.zip .ebextensions/ app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Basically the `app-new.zip` is the file that i am uploading to ElasticBeanstalk